# Should a numerical predictor be removed in favour of a logical predictor when both are highly correlated to each other?

Tags: correlation, predictive-models, data-preprocessing

The easier way to understand it might be with an easy example. Let's imagine we have 2 predictors/variables: hours_studied and exam_failed.

[image]

These two variables are highly correlated: -0.91, which is easily understandable when you plot the data:
[image]

Generally, out of a couple of correlated variables, I tend to remove the one with a higher average correlation to all predictors. In this case, let's imagine that the one to be removed is 'hours_studied'.

Even though theoretically it makes sense, I still consider 'hours_studied' to be probably a more informative predictor than 'exam_failed_binary'. Thus, is my original strategy flawed, or is it irrelevant to remove either of those?

A possible explanation might be that you should not remove predictors based on the correlation between different predictor classes. Correlation should only be performed between similar class predictors, in order to only remove highly correlated predictors that do not provide extra information in any other way.

Comment: No. If they represent the same information, as in one is obtained from another, then probably, but otherwise no. Unless you have a good reason to do so. Whether you would keep the numerical or categorical variable depends on your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's good to avoid [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) in your predictive variables. If one variable can be predicted by another then there's likely to not be information added.

You can remove these by any number of clustering approaches (e.g. [lasso](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-in-machine-learning-using-lasso-regression-7809c7c2771a)).  Searching for collinearity on cross-validated will also throw up plenty of relevant threads.

Furthermore from a causal perspective, one can also just use domain knowledge to retain the variable which makes more sense to be truly causing your target variable.

Comment: It is easy to advise dropping a variable if it is completely redundant, but this advice still raises the issue of when two variables are so strongly correlated that one should be dropped, and I don't have a precise rule either.  However, if the goal is prediction, keeping overlapping variables can improve a prediction at the cost of some redundancy. If the goal is more nearly explanation, parsimony is more highly prized. Outside of an experiment, at least some predictors being quite highly correlated with each other is normal, not pathological.

Comment: And one can test for the joint influence of the two variables with a "chunk" composite test having at least 2 degrees of freedom.  Collinearity does not hurt tests that allow inter-related predictors to combine forces (unlike individual tests of effects of one adjusted for the other).